# Same iOS App functionality, Different Names

Tags: ios, app-store, white-labelling

I have an App that uses a WebService and do some work,,, my question is, can I upload the same App (after changing the WS Link) but with different name?

I will rather get an answer from some users about spamming or something, but it isn't, the idea is business-wise,,, each client (client here is not the iOS User, it is a stand-alone company) want to purchase my App, will give me his WS URL, and I will just change the WS URL and put the company's icon and name and make a package for his company,,,

Hope to get help on that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do this as long as you mind your submission rate. On the spam note, if your not carful, you will be rejected.

In order to avoid this, you will want to change as much about the app as you can. At least color/graphics schemes (application wide).

> 2.20: Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

Answer (score 0):

I think it's okay if you change the URL and icon. It would be great if you can add a custom launch screen and/or if you can modify app's color scheme, too.

Comment: For sure I will change the main icon logo according to the company (this is the main idea, beside changing the WS URL), also, I do have different launch screen according to the company too... What I mainly want to know, shall I change the provisioning profile or anything such as the Bundle ID? Or I can just change the names and icons and upload? Also you have to keep in mind that on the same device, I may have multiple Apps (Same App with different name, so I can connect to different companies),,, hope you can help

Comment: What I mainly want to know, shall I change the provisioning profile or anything such as the Bundle ID? Or I can just change the names and icons and upload? Also you have to keep in mind that on the same device, I may have multiple Apps (Same App with different name, so I can connect to different companies),,, hope you can help..

Answer (score 0):

After several tests (which include installing the original App from the App Store, then try to test the new app with the different name), it always install over the same old one, so you can't do it on the same provisioning profile, by just changing the name on the Build Settings...

You have to make a different new provisioning profile with new Bundle ID and use it on the build, so each build will be treated as a new and unique build...

Thanks for the help though..